# Is use useQuery this way an antipattern?

Tags: reactjs, fetch, react-query

I have a block of react-query using typescript like this

```
export const useFoo = () =>
  useQuery(['example-key'], (): Nullable<Foo> => null);
```

after the initiation, i have a onClick handler that call useMutaion like that

```
export const useUpdateFoo = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  return useMutation(
    ['example-useMutation_key'],
    async () => {
      // api stuff, assume that this code return correct data
    },
    {
      onSuccess: (response) => {
        queryClient.setQueryData(['example-key'],() => response);
      },
    }
  );
};
```

My question is that an antipattern? My colleague say that if my useQuery doesn't **FETCH** anything so it shouldn't belong to use useQuery? If not, is there any limitation to this approach?

Comment: Are you using useFoo anywhere in the component? If not, there's no need to have useQuery at all.

Comment: yes, i use it in some components

Comment: It definitely looks fishy, maybe if you could describe your use case a bit more, I could offer alternatives, hard to say without additional context.